# Magento Disable Checkout if condition is false

Tags: magento2

I'm using Codazon one step checkout. I would like to disable the place order button until the condition is true.
How do i achieve this and which controller to edit

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link
https://meetanshi.com/blog/restrict-magento-2-checkout-based-on-various-conditions/

[Restrict Checkout](https://meetanshi.com/blog/restrict-magento-2-checkout-based-on-various-conditions/)